# bootstrap popover - reposition after removing dynamic content removed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've attached a fiddle that shows the issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/dxande6/nEYhD/50/

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="PersonalSettingsController">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <phone-button>Add Button</phone-button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
var app=angular.module("myApplication", []);

app.controller('PersonalSettingsController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.phoneOptionButtons = [
        {name:'CVOIP'},
        {name:'Home'},
        {name:'Cell'},
        {name:'Work'}
    ];


});

app.directive('phoneButton', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope: {
      key: '=',
      pi: '=',
      ci: '='
    },
    template: "<button class='rule-button' type='button' change-modal></button>",
    link: function(scope, elements, attrs) {
      elements.bind('click', function() {});
    }
  }
});

app.directive('changeModal', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var html =     "<div id='who-cares'>" +
                            "<button ng-click='addOption(pob.name, $index)' class='rule-option' ng-repeat='pob in $parent.phoneOptionButtons'>" +
                                "<div class='{{ pob.name | lowercase }}' name='{{pob.name}}' index='{{$index}}'>{{ pob.name }}</div>" +
                            "</button>" +
                        "</div>";
      var popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);
      var options = {
        trigger: 'click',
        content: popOverContent,
        placement: "top",
        html: true
      };

      $(element).popover(options);

      scope.addOption = function(name, index) {
        // Get index based on name, allows us to re-use
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.$parent.phoneOptionButtons.length; i++) {
            if (scope.$parent.phoneOptionButtons[i].name === name) {
                scope.$parent.phoneOptionButtons.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute:
    top: 50%;
}
```

Click one of the button and a bootstrap popover will display.
I've got a bootstrap popover that has dynamic content, in this case, 4 buttons.  If you click on one of the popover buttons it is removed from the popover.  Notice the position of the popover is no longer directly above the button.

Now click the button to remove the popover.  Click it again.  The popover is now positioned over the button appropriately.

Is there any way, when you click on one of the buttons in the popover, it can automatically reposition itself over the button (centered)?

This has been causing me trouble for quite some time and I can't seem to get it resolved.
Any help is appreciated.

-Dean